# $i = \frac{dq}{dt}$ implies $\Delta q = i \Delta t$? Incorrect mathematics used as some kind of hand-wavy justification for an engineering equation?

Tags: derivatives, physics, electromagnetism

I am reading an electrical engineering textbook that states that the relationship between current $i$, charge $q$, and time $t$ is

$$i = \dfrac{dq}{dt} \tag{1}$$

Based on this, the authors then state that

$$\Delta q = i \Delta t \tag{2}$$

This set off alarm bells in my head. Now, (2) may actually be true, but using (1) as some kind of implication for (2) just seems like incorrect mathematics. If I had to fill in the blanks of the authors' thinking, it seems to me that they were likely rationalising this through the derivation of the derivative

$$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

But, nonetheless, I don't see how, mathematically, $i = \dfrac{dq}{dt}$ implies $\Delta q = i \Delta t$.

Am I mistaken here, or is this actually incorrect mathematics used as some kind of hand-wavy justification for an engineering equation?

Comment: The reality is $\Delta q \approx i\Delta t$. This is a common practice for differentials. Tangent lines represent the best linear approximation to a function at a point. The $q_2$ you get from $\Delta q = q_2 - q_1$ is the value along the tangent line. It is not the value of the function itself in general.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But isn't the point of the limits in the mathematical derivation of the derivative that it gets rid of the $\approx$ and makes it a $=$? The $\approx$ may still be used in physics/engineering calculations (for instance, in numerical calculations/approximations), since taking the limit may not be valid, but I don't think the point you're making is true in general, no?

Comment: No. $\Delta t$ here is a nonzero quantity. No limit is being taken. Physics and engineering textbooks have a penchant for playing fast and loose with differentials and claiming equality when approximate equality should be understood.

Comment: I should also note that equality *does* hold if $i$ is constant in time.

Comment: Also holds if they are talking about average current.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But for (1) to imply (2) requires the use of limits, since we're going from $\dfrac{dq}{dt}$ to $\dfrac{\Delta q}{\Delta t}$, and going in the opposite direction requires limits in the first place to derive $\dfrac{dq}{dt}$, no? I mean, limits are fundamental to the derivation/definition of the derivative, so I don't understand how they can be ignored; using the concept of derivatives implies the presence/use of limits.

Comment: Without actually showing us what they are trying to establish and how, there's really no way to answer this question without guessing.

Comment: @DanielV I'm not asking how *they* got from (1) to (2), what I'm asking is whether it is even mathematically correct that (1) implies (2). As far as I can tell, given the definition of derivatives, (1) does not imply (2), which is my point. But maybe my understanding of the definition of derivatives is incorrect.

Comment: See my comment to @Nate Eldredge. If $i$ is time-independent, then how does that factor into the definition/derivation of derivative $$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ in order to conclude that (1) does indeed imply (2)? This might be what enables it to make mathematical sense, and where the answer to my confusion lies.

Comment: @ThePointer You're missing my point. They are claiming equality. It is not actually equality. Open up your calculus book and look at the differentials section probably in Chapter 3 for more information. Do not always trust that physics books are treating mathematics correctly. They rarely do. (But it's close enough to correct that no one really cares besides us math dorks.) The key is that for $\Delta x$ small enough, $\displaystyle \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ will be reasonably close to $y'(x)$ (by virtue of the convergence of the limit) so that $\Delta y \approx y'(x)\Delta x$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Oh, I see what you're saying. A "differential" is an entirely different concept to the definition of derivatives.

Comment: Yep! Exactly. Check my edit on the comment for more clarity. They are very closely related, but they are distinct ideas.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, I see what you mean. Thank you for taking the time to clarify this. Feel free to post an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @ThePointer Then the answer is "sometimes" and "depends on what they mean".

Answer (score 2):

Integrate both side by $dt$ from $t = 0$ to $t=Δt$. You should get something like this,
$$ i Δt = \int_{q(t=0)} ^{q(t=Δ t)} dq = q(Δ t) - q(0),$$
which you can define $Δq = q(Δ t) - q(0)$.

Oh, I just see that $i$ need to be time-independent, otherwise this won't work. Anyway, this should confirm your doubt.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it seems that you're assuming that $dt = \Delta t$ and $dq = \Delta q$, which is not true, as I showed.

Comment: No need to assume that, $\Delta t$ can be something large. As long as $i$ is time-independent, this still works.

Comment: If $i$ is time-independent, we can also get the conclusion by noticing that $dq/dt$ is constant and therefore $q$ is a linear function of $t$, $q(t) = q_0 + it$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hmm, if $i$ is time-independent, then how does that factor into the definition/derivation of derivative $$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ in order to conclude that (1) does indeed imply (2)? This might be what enables it to make mathematical sense, and where the answer to my confusion lies.

Comment: @ThePointer: It says that the limit has the same value, namely $i$, no matter what $x$ is (or in this case $t$).  Intuitively, this means that the function $q(t)$ has the same slope at every point, so it must be a straight line.  More formally, one uses the mean value theorem to show that a function with a constant derivative must be linear.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is only true when $i$ is constant otherwise we would have

$$i=\frac{dq}{dt}\implies \int_{q_i}^{q_f}dq=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}idt\implies\boxed{\Delta q=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}idt}$$

When current is constant then$$\displaystyle\Delta q= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}idt=i\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt=i\Delta t$$